# Setting programs to launch on Windows start in a particular order

Tags: windows-10

I want to:

1. make certain programs launch on Windows startup, and
2. make sure they launch in a particular order.

Is it possible with Windows 10 without using third party programs?

Comment: Just write a batch file that starts up programs in the order you want and execute that batch file on startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open a notepad window
2. Type `start path`, path means the path to the program you want to startup. Do this for as much programs as you need. After each program insert a `return`. It will start up in the order from top to the bottom.
3. Save the file as `startup.bat`.
4. Place it in the startup folder.